# How can I clone/copy the jQuery object into a new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery on my main page and would like to clone/copy the main page version of it inside my iframe, so that I can extend that version with specific plugins that are not relevant on the main page.

How can accomplish do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not simply load jquery in the other page the normal way?

Answer (score 1):

No. That's is not cloning process. You require to put the code for your iframe elements separately or in combined logics.

You cannot clone the function for another scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a `<script>` tag for jquery in the head of the iframe's document. That will provoke the iframe into loading jQuery.

Don't forget that you have to use the jQuery constructor that takes a 2nd parameter specifying the `htmlDocument` when you create an element in a different document and when you do element queries in a different document.

Here is an [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw9voh73/) that puts the main document jquery into an iframe.

CORS applies here, if the iframe is not in the same document, it will not let you "reach into" the iframe. If you control the page, you can use postMessage to get around the security barrier.

Comment: Problem is I'm not necessarily in control of the naming or placement of the jQuery script on the filesystem. Is it not possible to copy jQuery from the jQuery object in the parent and assign it to a variable in the iframe?

Comment: @transporter_room_3 It is, you can probably find the `<script>` that has jquery in the src with `$('script[src*="jquery"]')`